# Deriving the Marginal Distribution Function from joint distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

How to find marginal distribution function from joint distribution function

$$f_{X,N}(x,n)={(p^x\cdot(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot e^{-λ} λ^n)\over x!(n-x)!}$$

Do you just take $\mathsf E(X)=\mathop{\sum \sum}_{0\leq x<n<\infty} x\;f_{X,N}(x,n)$?

Apprecate English not strong.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

That's the expectation.  However, close.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}x) & = \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{x!\,(n-x)!} & \text{because }0\leq x< n < \infty \\[2ex] & = \frac{(\lambda p)^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}\sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{n-x}\lambda^{n-x}}{(n-x)!} & \text{remove factors unrelated to }n\\[-1ex] && \text{leaving factors related to }n-x \\[2ex] & = \frac{(\lambda p)^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{k}\lambda^{k}}{k!}& \text{change of variable }k\leftarrow (n{-}x)\end{align}$$

Now, do you recognise the series in the last line?

> $$e^{r} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{r^k}{k!}$$

Comment: I believe I still miss something last line. Thank you very much Graham. Help very appreciated. Changing terminal was what forgotten.